# Is there a connection between the solar wind and the cosmic radiation?

Tags: the-sun, radiation, solar-wind, proton

Cosmic radiation consists of high-energetic particles, mostly protons, that come amongst others from supernovae and our sun, right?

The solar wind also consists of charged particles, like protons and electrons, and comes, of course, from the sun.

So I wonder whether there is a connection between these two? Is the solar wind a part of the cosmic radiation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cosmic radiation (which consists of high-energy protons and atomic nuclei) comes from the sun, other stars, even other galaxies.

Solar wind is a part of that - the part coming from the sun, which mostly consists of [electrons, protons and alpha particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind) with kinetic energy between 0.5 and 10 keV

Comment: Protons up to ~10MeV also originate from the sun, but as coronal mass ejections distinct from the regular old solar wind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Generally, high solar activity deflects or absorbs truly cosmic rays. There's [an eleven year cycle](http://neutronm.bartol.udel.edu/catch/cr3.html) in the intensity of [extrasolar cosmic rays reaching the earth](https://abruptearthchanges.com/2018/01/14/climate-change-grand-solar-minimum-and-cosmic-rays/).